# Does boto2 use http or https to upload files to s3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

I noticed that uploading small files to S3 bucket is very slow. For a file with size of 100KB, it takes 200ms to upload. Both the bucket and our app are in Oregon. App is hosted on EC2.

I googled it and found some blogs; e.g. http://improve.dk/pushing-the-limits-of-amazon-s3-upload-performance/
It's mentioned that http can bring much speed gain than https.
We're using boto 2.45; I'm wondering whether both uses https or http by default? Or is there any param to configure this behavior in boto?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the EC2 instance? If its a shitty t2 you might get poorer (But I'd be surprised if this poor) network performance. You should also look at using an S3 VPC endpoint (potentially) for high throughput to S3 frmo a private subnet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried boto3, which has a nice parameter "use_ssl" in connection constructor. However, it turned out that boto3 is significantly slower than boto2.... there're actually already many posts online about this issue.

Finally, I found that, in boto2, there's also a similar param "is_secure"

self.s3Conn = S3Connection(config.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, config.AWS_SECRET_KEY, host=config.S3_ENDPOINT, is_secure=False)

Setting is_secure to False saves us about 20ms. Not bad..........

Answer (score 1):

The [boto3 client](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/core/session.html) includes a `use_ssl` parameter:

> **use_ssl** (*boolean*) -- Whether or not to use SSL. By default, SSL is used. Note that not all services support non-ssl connections.

Looks like it's time for you to move to boto3!